# including spring properties in logback pattern

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I would like to include some spring properties in my logback.xml pattern, but until I know it is not possible due to application.properties is loaded after logback.xml

There is a way to include a property from application.properties or from project pom.xml?

This is my logback code:

> %d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ"} [%p] %c ${project.artifactId} - %msg%n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dedicated property called `springProperty` which you can use in your Logback configuration file.

```
<configuration>
    <springProperty name="artifactId" source="project.artifactId"/>
    ...
    <fileNamePattern> ... ${artifactId} ... </fileNamePattern>
    ...
</configuration>
```

The `source` attribute should match the key in your *application.properties*. The `name` attribute is used to refer the value inside the configuration.